# Processing gesture while screen off (Android)

Tags: java, android

Is there anyway to keep a service running which while the screen is off and device is locked, can still process gestures and respond to them accordingly? (Such as muting device, manipulating volume,etc) particularly on Android 5.0 (I know the LG G3 has a knockcode feature, so I guess it's possible...maybe something similar?)

Thanks

Comment: By gestures do you mean responding to button presses or responding to screen touches?

Comment: Screen touches and finger patterns in particular

Comment: "I know the LG G3 has a knockcode feature" -- are you building your own hardware, as LG did?

Comment: I was wondering if it's possible using any android device/if it's a feature introduced in android 5.0? Or is this hardware related?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but this is a kernel feature. You need to have a compatible kernel before attempting to code this app.